# Get values formatted on tooltip

Tags: java, gwt, highcharts

How to manipulate the value in tooltip to get values in 2 decimal values after point in gwt highcharts java. I have some value on tooltip which look like: k_g1: 145,2568962789 and I want to format it to get only 2 numbers after comma, like k_g1:145,25.

Comment: You can set valeDecimals property in tooltip to 2 and get it done as I did here http://jsfiddle.net/aVDLg/ or you can always write your own formatting function in formatter method provided in tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the tooltip behavior by setting the desired values in the `tooltip` object.

In your case `valueDecimals` property of tooltip is of your concern. [See](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) the api docs for the same.

```
tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
```

Check out: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/valuedecimals/)

Comment: thank you, but that is for js, i need a sample for using in java